# TCP Connection to Google SQL gives OperationalError (from containerized app in GKE)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql, gke-networking

I have a Flask & SQLAlchemy service containerized and deployed to Google Kubernetes Engine and I establish a TCP connection to my database in Google SQL. When developing locally, the connection is successful because I've added my computer's IP address to the "authorised networks" for my database instance in Google SQL. However, when I deploy my service to a cluster in GKE, the TCP connection to the db gives OperationalError.

I believe this error is mainly because the IP address of my cluster is not added to "authorised networks" (to verify I deleted my computer's IP from authorised networks and tested the connection locally and got the same OperationalError). I've authorized both the endpoint IP of my cluster, pod address range (see below image) and also the IP exposed to the internet for my service, however, both didn't seem to work. In order authorize my GKE cluster to connect the db in Google SQL, which IP should I add to the "authorized networks"?

Here's how I build the connection URL:

```
class Config(object):
    if os.environ.get('ENVIRONMENT') == 'production':
        log.debug("You're using the remote db URL!!!")
        db_user = os.environ.get("DB_USER")
        db_pass = os.environ.get("DB_PASS")
        db_name = os.environ.get("DB_NAME")
        db_hostname = os.environ.get("DB_HOST")
        db_port = os.environ.get("DB_PORT")

        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_pass}@{db_hostname}:{db_port}/{db_name}"
```

[image]

Comment: How is your cloud sql instance configured (network portion)? Public, private ip, both? Which VPC is it bound to? Same as gke cluster (default/default)? How do you connect to the sql instance (what is the resulting conn string)? What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: are you using private ip ? if so u must have a peering and a service connection. once you are not using private , you can connecti via Socket or using cloud sql proxy, take a look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rh1EzNey3VQ  , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKoaiH_xYB8  ,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0dLD0Adslk&t=2s

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding the entire node network to Authorized Networks, I'd suggest using the Cloud SQL proxy to authorize your connections. There is a how-to guide here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine